# if statement skipped even if it's equal to true in javascript extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a problem concerning an if statement.

my code is this :

```
if(fromE130Val==="no"){
       //even if the test below is equal to true, it's does not goes here !                             
 }
 else{
        //it comes here !
 }
```

[image]

as you can see in the image below, when i debug , the if statement returns true, but the next instruction goes to the else statement !

i don't know why i have this behaviour !

Any help please ?

Comment: If it's going into the else block, it's not evaluating to true. Post a test case.

Comment: I think that it's evaluated to true. As you can see i posted an image while i was debugging. (the black line)

Comment: It can't be. Unless javascript is broken.

Comment: it could be a timing issue too. If Monster is looking at a value set by an async event ... this could happen.